# Unable to launch chrome browser on Android device

Tags: android, appium, mobile-browser

I want to launch chrome browser on simulator, I am getting below error
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session.

Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '61.0.3163.0'. See https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md for more details.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
, os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: driver.version: AppiumDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '61.0.3163.0'. See https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md for more details.

I am using latest Http client (7.2.0) and selenium version(3.141.59).

Comment: how you are running appium using studio or from node source ?

Answer (score 0):

The chrome browser version installed in emulator is 61 and chrome driver that can automate chrome browser version 61 is https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.34/. So update  chromedriver.exe from link provided.